# Solve this equation with fixed point iteration method in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, equation, nonlinear-functions, fixed-point-iteration

```
f(x) = x^2- 2x - 3 = 0
```

How can I solve this equation non-linear, and used fixed point iteration method in Python ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving Quadratic Equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398427/solving-quadratic-equation)

Comment: Note that also the Newton's method is a fixed-point iteration.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Point Iteration

> f(x) = x^2-2x-3 = 0 ⇒ x(x-2) = 3  ⇒ x = 3/(x-2)

```
import math

def g(x):
   if 2 == x:
       return x + 1e-10
   return 3/(x-2)

def quadratic(ff,x=0):
    while abs(x-ff(x)) > 1e-10:
        x = ff(x);
    return x

print(quadratic(g))
```

> -1

root finding formula

```
# -*- coding:utf8 -*-
import math
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    ''' ax² + bx + c = 0
        return
        True  : all real number
        Fasle :  no solutions
        (x1,x2)
    '''
    if not isinstance(a, (int, float)):
        raise TypeError('a is not a number')
    if not isinstance(b, (int, float)):
        raise TypeErrot('b is not a number')
    if not isinstance(c, (int, float)):
        raise TypeError('c is not a number')
    derta = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if a == 0:
        if b == 0:
            if c == 0:
                return True
            else:
               return False
        else:
            x1 = -c / b
            x2 = x1
            return x1, x2
    else:
        if derta < 0:
            return False
        else:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(derta)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(derta)) / (2 * a)
            return x1, x2

print(quadratic(1, -2, -3))
```

> (3.0, -1.0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quadratic equation that you can solve using a closed-form expression (i.e. no need to use fixed-point iteration) as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation).

In this case you will have two solutions:

```
x1 = -(p/2) + math.sqrt((p/2)**2-q)
x2 = -(p/2) - math.sqrt((p/2)**2-q)
```

where p is you first coefficient (-2 in your example) and q is your second coefficient (-3 in your example).

For the general case, you will have to check the expression inside the sqrt operator for being greater or equal to zero. If it is smaller than zero, the equation will not have a real-number solution. If it is equal to zero, the two solutions are equal (called a *double root*).

Comment: Using a fixed-point method is mandated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible iteration is with

```
f(x) = 2 + 3 / x.
```

The derivative is

```
f'(x) = - 3 / x²
```

so that the iterations will  converge for `x² > 3`.

Starting from `2`, the iterates are

```
2, 7/2, 20/7, 61/20, 182/61, 547/182... -> 3
```

This doesn't work for the other root (which is negative) because negative values quickly become positive.

The formula used by @tinyhare,

```
f(x) = 3 / (x - 2)
```

has the derivative

```
f'(x) = - 3 / (x - 2)²
```

and certainly stays and converges in the negatives.

```
-2, -3/4, -12/11, -33/34, -102/101, -303/304, ... -> -1
```

Note that in both cases, the numerator is every time off by one, while the denominator increases regularly.